# pd.Timestamp.replace iteratively

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

data

```
res=pd.DataFrame({'period':['s', 'e', 's', 'e'], 'lapse':[-1.0, 1.0, -1, 1],'date':['1975-02-25 09:39:39.914889', '1976-03-25 09:41:09.103102', '1978-05-25 10:39:58.352073', '1979-09-25 10:40:06.266782']})
```

I need to iteratively select `lapse==-1` lapses and change the `hour` and `minute`

Using the following, I am able to select and change them but that changes the year too.

```
res['date']=pd.to_datetime(res['date'])
a=res[(res['lapse']==-1.0) & (res['period']=='s')]
a['date']=pd.Timestamp.replace(a.loc[0,'date'], hour=18, minute=15)
```

[image]

Thats not what I want. I am dealing with 0ver 20,000 land records and I would need to iterate through them all. I tried

```
import datetime
for index, row in a.iterrows():
    print(row['date'])
    row['date']=pd.Timestamp.replace(row['date'], hour=17, minute=15)
```

Desired outcome

[image]

Comment: VM['key'] = 0
EM['key'] = 0

df = VM.merge(EM, on='key', how='outer')

df['x'] =df[['Latitude_x','Longitude_x']].agg(list,1)
df['y'] =df[['Latitude_y','Longitude_y']].agg(list,1)
s =(pd.DataFrame(haversine_distances(np.radians(VM[['Latitude','Longitude']]),np.radians(EM[['Latitude','Longitude']]))\
              * 6371,index=VM['Place'], columns=EM['City']))
s1=s.le(3000)
s1 = s1.assign(Matched_Cols=s1.agg(lambda s: s.index[s].values, axis=1)).explode('Matched_Cols')
s1
df['d'] = paired_distances(df['x'].to_list(),df['y'].to_list())*100

Comment: import os
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame({'a':[12,89, 2], 'b':[3,7,5],'c':[12,80,4]})
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\kalan\OneDrive\Desktop\dga')

l=['a','b','c']


for x in l:
    if x=='a':
        df[x] = df[x]+100
    elif x=='b':#if true skip
        if df[x].sum()%3==0:
            continue        
        df[x]=df[x]+500
        j =('s','s')
        if len(j)==1:
            df[x] +=1000
        else:
            df[x]=df[x]
            
    else:
        df[x] =df[x]+300
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f'{x}'+'.csv'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter rows of `date` by mask and change datetime only for these values:

```
res['date']=pd.to_datetime(res['date'])
m= (res['lapse']==-1.0) & (res['period']=='s')
res.loc[m, 'date']= res.loc[m, 'date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(hour=18, minute=15))
#alternative solution
#res.loc[m, 'date']= res.loc[m, 'date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(hour=18, minute=15)
print (res)
 period  lapse                          date
0      s   -1.0 1975-02-25 18:15:39.914888992
1      e    1.0 1976-03-25 09:41:09.103102016
2      s   -1.0 1978-05-25 18:15:58.352072992
3      e    1.0 1979-09-25 10:40:06.266782016
```